# Why can't we use a third party website to make a csrf attack?

Tags: web-application, csrf

First of all, I'm quite new to web security so this might be a dumb question. Also English is not my native language so there might be some errors.

I understand that by having a csrf token as a hidden parameter in a form or HTTP header, an attacker cannot use something like an image tag to perform an action on the user's behalf. I also understand that if you have an XSS on the website, you can steal the csrf token and perform any action.

What I don't understand however is what prevent an attacker to his own domain, like `evilsite.com`, use JavaScript to make a GET request, analyses the response, extract the csrf token and submit the form to make some action. As you can make a post request with JQuery for example, you should be able to send the request and trick the user.

There should be a mechanism that I don't understand here because it makes no sense for me right now. What don't I understand?

Comment: The best answer: try to do it yourself! It's not a hard experiment and you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents a website from reading another website, which also prevents it from extracting the token to perform a CSRF attack.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, we have to trust the browser as this is client-side. Am I right?

Comment: @o2640110: That's right.

Comment: Is there a way to do a server-side check to add further protection? (Other than the csrf token)

Comment: @o2640110 Some people check the referer, but an attacker could force the browser to not send that header. Note that the CSRF provides enough protection already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers.